# Trying to create a decent semi-flat design. Failing

Tags: font, typography, graphic-design, skinning, flat-design

We hit a snag in our project: We've only got a few weeks till launch and the designer who was to make a skin for our product has not delivered the (very) goods. I took a stab at creating a skin for the product and it has some good ideas but also some issues. I'm not fond of the typography and I attempted to add some 3-dimensionality with the buttons but it's looking tacky.

I should mention that my design philosophy is to favor a mostly flat design but not in a fetishistic way; that is, I like flat design for its simplicity but not at the expense of usability. I like the use of a third dimension to enhance the experience, but not for decoration. I.e. I'm not trying to copy Metro.

I've attached one of the more representative menus on the app. Any graphic-oriented designers in here want to weigh in on possible font choices or fixes for the tacky buttons? Suggestions in general?

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for 'graphic oriented designers' I'd suggest moving this to Graphic Design rather than UX.

Comment: Yes I suppose that would make sense.

Comment: This is really just a 'critique my website / project' question which doesn't really work on Q&A websites. There is no correct answer here and it's only really of use / interest to you and not to anyone else, so such questions aren't really encouraged here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your design is, way too bold text , very dark shadows plus colors are not that awesome try [FlatUI colors](http://www.flatuicolors.com)
Moreover head over to [Dribble(tag flat ui)](http://dribbble.com/search?q=flat%20ui) you can find a ton of UI design inspirations there.